# EF manual attach list of entities into parent entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

```
class Student{
public string Name {get; set;}

public EntityCollection<Info> Infos {get; set;}
}

class Info{
public string Title {get; set;}
public Student Student {get; set;}
}
```

I have two entities like this. First I will query one student entity

```
var student = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentId = 1);
```

Then I query Info list of this student in a separate query

```
var infos = from c in db.Info where c.StudentId = 1 and ....
```

If I loop though infos and add it manual into student.Infos, it will cause insert new row

```
foreach(info in infos){
student.Infos.Add(info);
}
```

How to attach list of info into student entity without insert new row into Info table when db.SaveChanges(). Like

```
student.Infos = infos
```

Answer (score 0):

EF does the work for you behind the scenes when you use navigation properties. It's not just a data layer to load data singularly but rather it's set up with the relationships between the data and is capable of loading an entire object graph of related data either in one hit (eager loaded) or on-demand (lazy loaded)

Firstly: you can update your Info collections to `ICollection<Info>` or `List<Info>`. I opt for `List<Info>` because I commonly use `.AddRange()`.  Also, mark it as virtual to enable EF proxies and lazy loading.

From there, to access the Infos on a Student you can just use:

```
var student = db.Students.Include(s => s.Infos).SingleOrDefault(s => s.StudentId = 1);
```

This will eager-load the Infos for the selected student. No need to load them separately.

If you leave off the .Include(..) then you can still access the Infos (provided the DbContext is still in scope) though this will trigger additional SQL calls to load the Infos. (Lazy loaded)

When loading data to send outside of the scope of the DbContext, such as returned from an API call, or sent to a view, it's recommended to compose a DTO or ViewModel with just the fields that you need from the various entities, then perform a `.Select()` to populate them, and return the DTOs not the entities. This avoids problems with lazy loading calls after a DbContext has been disposed and unexpected performance issues if lazy loading is triggered due to serialization or the like.